# PHP array containing 0/

Tags: php, preg-grep

hi I have array of elements containing pattern like 
$arr = array ('0/' ,'0/12/3','1/2')
i need to have array of "0/" elements i've tried to use command

**arr_with_zero_slash = preg_grep('@$[0-9]/$@',$arr)**

but function works only witch pattern like 1/ , 2/ and so one. This is because 0/ is treated as special sign but i dont know how to deal with that. Any ideas?

Comment: *"0/ is treated as special sign"* -- there is nothing special with `0/`

Comment: fyi, that "command" is not valid PHP code. Also, `[0-9]` is getting you all numbers from 0 to 9, you only want 0, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean:
Cycle through array $arr using a foreach-loop, and unset (remove) all elements that don't start with '0/'...

```
$arr = array ('0/' ,'0/12/3','1/2');
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
  if(substr($value,0,2)<>"0/"){
    unset($arr[$key]);
  }
}
```

With:

```
$arr = array ('0/' ,'0/12/3','1/2')
```

this will be the outcome:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "0/" [1]=> string(6) "0/12/3" }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all elements starting with `0/` try this:

```
<?php
$arr = array ('0/' ,'0/12/3','1/2', '1/0/4');
$arr_with_zero_slash = preg_grep('@^0/@',$arr);
print_r($arr_with_zero_slash);
```

This will output

```
Array (
    [0] => 0/
    [1] => 0/12/3
)
```

Removed the first `$` since it's a [meta-character](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php).

Changed `[0-9]` to `0`, since you only want `0/` and not `1/`, `2/` etc.

Removed the second `$` since you also want `0/12/3`.

Comment: This would also match a string like `1/0/4`.

Comment: @simon Right, my fault, added `^`